# when, once and as soon as + present prefect and simple present of a verb

Tags: tense

I am wondering if I can use either the simple present or the present perfect for the conjunctions: once, when, and as soon as. For example,

(1a) As soon as I save enough money, I will travel around the world.

(1b) As soon as I **have** saved enough money, I will travel around the world.

(2a) Once you learn how to balance on ice properly, you can skate easily.

(2b) Once you **have** learned how to balance on ice properly, you can skate easily.

(3a) When they finish the meal, I will wash up and make coffee for them.

(3b) When they **have** finished the meal, I will wash up and make coffee for them.

Is it grammatically correct to use either tense for these conjunctions?

Comment: Yes, all of your examples are correct and understandable.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, all of those are fine. The nice thing about the present perfect is that while it might refer to the past, it behaves grammatically like the simple present.